# World Bank API to pandas DF

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to convert World Bank's API into pandas DF format from the API link: http://api.worldbank.org/countries/indicators/6.0.GDP_growth?per_page=100&date=2000:2015&format=json

Which has the page response of:

> [{"page":1,"pages":147,"per_page":"2","total":294},[{"indicator":{"id":"6.0.GDP_growth","value":"GDP
>   growth (annual %)"},"country":{"id":"L5","value":"Andean
>   Region"},"value":null,"decimal":"0","date":"2001"},{"indicator":{"id":"6.0.GDP_growth","value":"GDP
>   growth (annual %)"},"country":{"id":"L5","value":"Andean
>   Region"},"value":null,"decimal":"0","date":"2000"}]]

I'm trying to get a data frame similar to:

```
Out[253]:
Country Name    GDP_growth
0   Afghanistan 14.43474129
1   Albania 1.623698601
2   Algeria 3.299991384
3   American Samoa  ..
4   Andorra -1.760010328
```

Here are the commands I have called to date:

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen
In [2]:

import json
In [3]:

from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
In [4]:

request = Request('http://api.worldbank.org/countries/indicators/6.0.GDP_growth?per_page=100&date=2000:2015&format=json')
In [5]:

response = urlopen(request)
In [6]:

elevations = response.read()

data = json.loads(elevations)

json_normalize(data['indicator'])
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 json_normalize(data['indicator'])
>
> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Would appreciate help on the last line.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`data` is a list at this moment. You see it a bit better, when you pretty-print it:

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(data)
```

The first item with an `indicator` field is `data[1][0]`.

Comment: Thanks, but how do you make it such that you are only accessing the Country name, GDP growth values and years columns?

Comment: `for item in data[1]: country = item['country']['value'], gdp_growth = item['value'], year = item['date'] # then do something with them`

Comment: I tried this but it came as error:

for item in data[1]:
    country = item['country']['value'],
    gdp_growth = item['value'],
    year = item['date']
    
country1 = pd.DataFrame(country)
gdp_growth1 = pd.DataFrame(gdp_growth)
year1 = pd.DataFrame(year)

df_JSON = pd.DataFrame.merge(country1, gdp_growth1, year1, left_index=True, right_index=True)
df_JSON = ['country', 'gdp_growth', 'year']

df_JSON.head()

Comment: In this case I suggest you take the time reading through these first: https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/ and https://www.codecademy.com/learn/python